# Can I use a separate query plan cache per session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

I have a multi-tenant ASP.NET application, and our database is set up with soft deletes. Initially, we handled the restriction of data directly at the query level, e.g:

```
var foos = context.Foos.Where(foo => !foo.Deleted && foo.TenantId = currentTenantId).ToList();
```

As you can imagine, this bloats all of the queries in our data access layer, and makes the API very vulnerable if one forgets to add the correct filter conditions. We have decided to apply global filtering to the context with `Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6`:

```
public class FooDataContextFactory
{
    public FooDataContext CreateContext()
    {
        var context = new FooDataContext();

        context.Filter<Foo>(collection => collection.Where(foo=> !foo.Deleted));

        var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "TenantId"))
        {
            var currentTenantId = int.Parse(principal.FindFirst("TenantId").Value);
            context.Filter<Foo>(collection => collection.Where(foo => foo.TenantId == currentTenantId));
        }

        return context;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for a single user. However, when you switch tenant, we have issues with the filter expression being saved in [the query plan cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper#32-query-plan-caching). This is a [known issue](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues/96#issuecomment-272582402) with Entity Framework Plus, and since it doesn't appear to be resolved, I need to find a workaround.

The most immediate solution I can think of is to associate the lifetime of the query plan cache to the current session, and when the user logs out or switches tenant, the cache is destroyed. Is this possible, and if so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I *doubt* that is possible.

Comment: The *only* way to do this as you are suggesting... and I mean there are much much better ways to do this without worrying about the cache.. is to create your context's in another application domain.  EF QueryCache is stored at the AppDomain level so throwing away an AppDomain throws away the cache.  Now that being said, what **Actual** problem are you having because of the query plan being cached?

Comment: I think the question states it pretty clearly - the query plan is cached, and it includes something along the lines of `WHERE TenantId = 3`. The value is not parameterized, so when I change tenant, the query does not return the correct results

Comment: Jonathan summarized the problem quite well in the linked issue - "The real problem is the plan is cached with the expression before the interceptor is invoked. That means two contexts with a different filter but with the same query will use the same execution plan which is very bad since not the same filter need to be applied."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same problem and tried to work with Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6 with the same issues. I found that the zzzprojects team also has [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) which works much better for this purpose. The query that is cached is parameterized and the value is injected at runtime using the selector function you provide.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using EntityFramework.DynamicFilters;

public class Program
{   
    public class CustomContext : DbContext
    {
        private int _tenantId;

        public int GetTenantId()
        {
            return _tenantId;
        }

        // Call this function to set the tenant once authentication is complete.
        // Alternatively, you could pass tenantId in when constructing CustomContext if you already know it
        // or pass in a function that returns the tenant to the constructor and call it here.
        public void SetTenantId(int tenantId)
        {
            _tenantId = tenantId;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Filter applies to any model that implements ITenantRestrictedObject
            modelBuilder.Filter(
                "TenantFilter",
                (ITenantRestrictedObject t, int tenantId) => t.TenantId == tenantId,
                (CustomContext ctx) => ctx.GetTenantId(), // Might could replace this with a property accessor... I haven't tried it
                opt => opt.ApplyToChildProperties(false)
            );
        }
    }

    public interface ITenantRestrictedObject
    {
        int TenantId { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have looked into this as another possible workaround. Unfortunately some of the filtering we do is also based on permissions, which are read from a table in the database, but you can't read from the database in the OnModelCreating method. It's not an ideal process - the permissions should be stored in the access token and not retrieved from database every time an endpoint is called - but it's what we have and I need to make it work.

Comment: This solution should work for permissions as well. You could read from permissions once before constructing `CustomContext` and pass the permissions in as a parameter or call a function like `SetTenantId` that accepts your permissions and stores them as a variable. Once set, you could read from that permission object like `(CustomContext ctx) => ctx.GetPermissions().Any({predicate for this object type})`.  You can also conditionally enable/disable dynamic filters by name, so you could instead have a function that is called after loading permissions that enables/disables filters.